# Read multiple contacts from single VCF file

Tags: c#, vcf-vcard

I want to read contacts from `.vcf` file using C#. I search for libraries that will do it, but I was not successful.
Thought.vCards or LumiSoft.Net just read first contact of vcf file.
I need to read all the contacts in the file.

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N;CHARSET=UTF-8;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:=D8=B3=D8=AA=D8=C=D8=B4;=D8=A7=D8=A8=D9=88=D8=A7=D9=84=D9=81=D8=B6=D9=84;;;
FN;CHARSET=UTF-8;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:=D8=A7=D8=A8=D9=88=D8=A7=D9=84=D9=81=D8=B6=D9=84=20=D8=B3=D8=AA=D8=A7=
=DB=8C=D8=B4
TEL;CELL:011111111111
BDAY:00010101
END:VCARD
BEGIN:VCARD
N:;rrrrrrrrrrr;;;
TEL:555555555
END:VCARD
BEGIN:VCARD
N:;ggggggg;;;
TEL:2222222222
END:VCARD
```

Comment: VCF file might contains multiple contacts, anyway?

Comment: VCF file like this
'BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N;CHARSET=UTF-8;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:=D8=B3=D8=AA=D8=A7=DB=8C=D8=B4;=D8=A7=D8=A8=D9=88=D8=A7=D9=84=D9=81=D8=B6=D9=84;;;
FN;CHARSET=UTF-8;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:=D8=A7=D8=A8=D9=88=D8=A7=D9=84=D9=81=D8=B6=D9=84=20=D8=B3=D8=AA=D8=A7=
=DB=8C=D8=B4
TEL;CELL:011111111
BDAY:00010101
END:VCARD
BEGIN:VCARD
N:;dsdas;;;
TEL:95555555555
END:VCARD'

Comment: Add it to your question. not as comment.

Comment: Okay, now add the code which you are using currently.

Comment: Please introduce library that can read this file.

Comment: You should introduce us what you have tried to do..

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Comment: What do you mean by language? I'm working with C # .

Comment: did you get solution ?